# ROS Fuerte 3D collision avoidance navigation with Kinect

Tags: navigation, kinect, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**[www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation)** link demonstrates a package for obstacle avoidance goal driven navigation. But, it is meant for ROS diamondback.Is there a similar version for ROS fuerte with kinect?The robot type is a non-ROS robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66560/ros-fuerte-3d-collision-avoidance-navigation-with-kinect/) by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A lot of this work has been rolled into the MoveIt! project. http://moveit.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0